# Which are the most suitable languages to apply Aspect's Theme approach?

Tags: aspectj, postsharp, aop, aspects

I am thinking about reading [Aspect-Oriented Analysis and Design: The Theme Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246748), yet I am hesitant. Is it possible to use what's taught in the book with AspectJ (for Java) or Post# in C#? Maybe with Aquarium in Ruby?

What would be the perfect language to suit the design process that's made with the book? I am more interested in the symmetrical approach to aspects.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just about every language can take advantage of aop. Even actionscript. Java and c# have some very nice frameworks. Postsharp works with c# and vb.net. you should definatly read that book. Thete is no perfect language but i suggest you try both java and c# using aspectj and spring for java and postsharp and spring.net for c# since it seems you are on a educational adventure.

I have not read the book but application of aspect oriented design can be done in almost any language. Start with what you know

Comment: I'm looking for a more "informed" answer. Yes I know there are a lot of frameworks, and yes I know that most of them do well when all we want is what people call an "asymmetrical" approach to aspects. But to go farther, to a "symmetrical" approach, it seems one needs a far more powerful mechanism from what I see is possible, for instance, with PostSharp. I am still not too sure even AspectJ, being a bit more expressive than PostSharp, is up to the task.

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on sharpcrafters.com to get an expert answer. I have to read more about this asym. Vs sym. approach.